# Xml & C# Deserialize Exception Error

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a XNA gaming project and keep receiving the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: There is an error in XML document (2, 2).

This is my Xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SplashScreen>
<Path>\SplashScreen\Game.png</Path>
</SplashScreen>
```

And this is my C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsGame3
{
    public class Manager<T>
    {
        public Type Type;

        public T Load(string Path)
        {
            T instance;
            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(Path))
            {
                XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(Type);
                instance = (T)xml.Deserialize(reader);
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public void save(string Path, object obj)
        {
            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path))
            {
                XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(Type);
                xml.Serialize(writer, obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code that uses the above `Manager` class:

```
public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
{
    this.Content = new ContentManager(Content.ServiceProvider, "Content");

    GameScreenManager = new Manager<GameScreen>();
    GameScreenManager.Type = currentScreen.Type;

    currentScreen = GameScreenManager.Load("SplashScreen.xml"); 
    currentScreen.LoadContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see if the type `T` that you are calling the `Load` method on matches proper casing of the root element name `SplashScreen` ?

Comment: Im sorry i am quite new to the xml side of things i don't know what you mean by proper casing of the root element name?

Comment: What class / object are you calling the Load method on? Can you paste it's definition?

Comment: You ClassName for T, i.e. GameScreen is not matching the Xml Root Element Name i.e. SplashScreen. Does the class definition of GameScreen have any XmlAttribute decorations?

Comment: Okay i see so it would need to be GameScreen and no i dont have any XmlAttribute decorations.

Comment: Sorry guys replacing SplasScreen with GameScreen is still throwing the same Xml Exeption.